# Remove / purge repository spotify and opensuse

Tags: updates, update-manager, repository

When I go to Software & Updates and then to Other Software I get this boxes unchecked: `http://repository.spotify.com stable non-free` and `http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/Horst3180/xUbuntu_15.10//`.

[image]

If I check them I am unable to download the updates, it will fail because of them, I guess.
I tried to install Spotify so I guess that is the reason they are there.
I have Ubuntu GNOME 15.10 on my machine. How to remove them from there? Thank you!

Comment: What exactly is your question? What do you want to achieve? And some terminal outputs of `sudo apt-get update` or `sudo apt-get install INSERT_PACKAGE_NAME_HERE` are better readable and more helpful than a screenshot usually. Copy it using the context menu or Ctrl+Shift+C (!) and paste it to your question ([edit] it, don't add output in comments) and format it as code (**`{}`** button in the editor or using Ctrl+K).

Comment: Is it possible to remove them from there?

Comment: If you simply uncheck them, they have no effect any more. It makes no difference whether a software source is unchecked or removed in that window. But if you really want to remove the source, there's a `Remove` button below the list. It will become clickable when you have selected a source in the list.

Comment: I kept clicking the right mouse button and nothing happen.

Answer (score 5):

Remove the files from the `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` directory. Try this command:

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/spotify.list
```

Then run `sudo apt-get update` and there should no longer be any references to `http://repository.spotify.com`

Comment: Are you sure that's the name of the file?

Comment: That's where it was under Peppermint OS 7

Comment: well I'll assume (possibly unwisely) it's the same

Comment: Worked great under Debian bullseye. Thank you.